# How can I use translations in a component title?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-localize-redux

I'm using react-translate-redux in a project for internationalization, but I don't know how to use translations in a component's properties. Specifically, I would like the title text of a component to be internationalized.

I would try the below,

```
<Button title={<Translate id="button">}>
```

but `Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'string'`.

How can I internationalize the title text?

Comment: Did you read e.g. https://ryandrewjohnson.github.io/react-localize-redux/getting-started/? The Translate component isn't your only option.

Comment: I'll see if I can use `getTranslate(state.locale)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use Translate Component you can't pass it as a prop, you have to pass it as a child component and render it with `this.props.children` in your Button Render method.

If Button Component is a external component you have to use prop function like in [this](https://ryandrewjohnson.github.io/react-localize-redux/getting-started/#4-add-translations-to-components) in Flavour 2